# python outlook delete messages greater than 30days old

Tags: python, datetime, time, outlook

***Desired Outcome:***
I'm trying to find every message in my outlook inbox that is older than 30 days and delete those messages.
***Issue:***
The issue is, I end up trying to compare **time** with **datetime.datetime**. So I searched and found that I might need to use **.strptime()**. But now I'm getting this error msg: **ValueError: time data '12/06/17 16:53:43' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'**. How can I get the result I'm looking for? Is there a better solution?
***Here is my code:***

```
for folder in default_folders:
    print( "Processing %s" % folder.Name )

    item = folder.Items
    msg = item.GetFirst()
    print type(msg.CreationTime) #this gives 'time' instance
    print msg.CreationTime # prints like: 12/7/17 10:50:05
    recv_time = datetime.strptime(str(msg.CreationTime), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").date() # <-- problem
    #datetime.replace(recv_time) i think this should be here
    past30days=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=30) # the date 30 days ago
    if recv_time > past30days: # if the recv_time date is greater than 30 days, do something 
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `%Y` for `%y` In the format string. `%Y` is for the year with four digits (2018) while `%y` is for 2 (18)